# How Do I Split A String By Capital Letter in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, web-services, soap

Im working on web services made in VB.NET
Im merging datasets and datatables from multiple web services into 1 dataset.
Im changing the format of some of the data, for example my web service lists the days of the week as a boolean but other web services are using a string like MoTuWedTh...
Im on a webservice now where they have used MoTuWeTh.... on some and MoTuWedTh... on others.
I was splitting the string into a char array and looping through it and using a if statement to say if char(0) & char(1) or  char(2) & char(3)... = Mo then Monday column(which is a boolean) = true.

This was working well until I got to this webservice, if I look for wednesday as We then the days afterthat are not recognised because thursday would become dT, friday would be hF etc.

My question is, how can i get the MoTuWed... string to split at each capital letter so it becomes Mo Tu Wed...

Or can you thing of another way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim Input As [String] = "MoTuWed"

Dim Dows As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(Input, "[A-Z][a-z]+")

' Dows has Mo, Tu, Wed
```